# Adapter for ListView on android scrolling issue

Tags: java, android, listview

I have created an adapter for my listview. for each listitem there's a checkbox on it. Whenever I scroll my listview it randomly set the checkbox to check on items.

Below is my getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_equipment_search, null);

    TextView serialno = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSerialNo); // Serial No
    TextView unitno = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtUnitNo); // Unit No
    CustomCheckBox chkEquipment = (CustomCheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.chkEquipment); // Select CheckBox


    final Equipment equipment = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    serialno.setText(equipment.GetSerialNo());
    unitno.setText(equipment.GetUnitNo());
    if (Equipment.EquipmentInList(equipment, selected))
        chkEquipment.setChecked(true, false);


    chkEquipment.setOnCheckedChangeListener((EquipmentSearchActivity) context);


    return vi;
}
```

Code on the Checkbox changed is

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    int pos = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEquipment)).getPositionForView(buttonView);

    if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        Equipment e = equipmentList.get(pos);
        if (isChecked && !Equipment.EquipmentInList(e, SelectedEquipment))
            SelectedEquipment.add(e);
        else if (!isChecked)
            SelectedEquipment = Equipment.RemoveEquipmentFromList(e, SelectedEquipment);
    }

    Button btnStoreEquipment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStoreEquipment);

    if (SelectedEquipment.size() > 0)
        btnStoreEquipment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        btnStoreEquipment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: you should create a arraylisrt which store all checkbox on listview after you base on item possion to set or unset checked state of checkbox  for / or to checkbox list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_equipment_search, null);
    enter code here
    TextView serialno = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSerialNo); // Serial No
    TextView unitno = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtUnitNo);

 CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chkEquipment);
        checkbox.setTag(new Integer(position));
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

            if (checkBoxState[position])
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
            else
                checkbox.setChecked(false);



        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Integer pos = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                if (isChecked) {

                    checkBoxState[pos.intValue()] = true;
                } else {
                    checkBoxState[pos.intValue()] = false;


                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your `getView` implementation. When scrolling, `getView` is always called, notice that since you only `inflate layout` if the `convertview` is `null`. What happens is that, your `chkEquipment` is recycled and used on other items.
So when you invoked

> if (Equipment.EquipmentInList(equipment, selected))
>           chkEquipment.setChecked(true, false);

Your actually making a reference to the `original checkbox` changing its original state.

You may read [ListViews and ViewHolder Pattern](https://www.ricston.com/blog/optimising-listview-viewholder-pattern/) for reference.